# ORMLite foriegncollection refresh

Tags: ormlite

ormlite-android-4.29, ormlite-core-4.29

I have a `ForiegnCollection` of PantryCheckLine objects like this in my PantryCheck class.

```
@ForeignCollectionField(eager = true, maxEagerForeignCollectionLevel = 1)
private ForeignCollection<PantryCheckLine> pantryCheckLines;
```

Let's say I had 3 PantryCheckLines objects and I deleted one. Then I want to delete the PantryCheck with combined PantryCheckLines of it. Everything seems working. But the size of the `ForiegnCollection`is not correct.

deleting method as follows.

```
PantryCheckLineRepo pantryCheckLineRepo =
    new PantryCheckLineRepo(DaoFactory.getPantryCheckLineDaoInstance());
Collection<PantryCheckLine> pantryCheckLinesCollection =
    this.getPantryCheckLines();
Log.v("pantrychecklines size", pantryCheckLinesCollection.size());
pantryCheckLineRepo.delete(pantryCheckLinesCollection);
Log.v("pantrychecklines", "deleted");
```

appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer specifically because I'm not sure what the `delete()` method is doing.  If you edit your question with more details about what `Dao` calls or `ForeignCollection` calls are being made, I can add details here.

The only way the collection size would be affected is if you used the `remove(Object)` method on the collection itself.  If you used the `Dao` to delete the item behind the scenes then the collection would not know that the delete happened and its eager fetched internal list size would not be affected.  The lazy collections (`eager = false`) always go to the database so either `remove(Object)` or `dao.delete(Object)` would work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Really appreciate your thoughts, but I got to work this in a different way. The above problem occurred because the ForeignCollection was not regenerated/refreshed.